# How can you create a named argument without ref or out in Roslyn for a method?

Tags: c#, roslyn

When creating a named argument for a constructor, I am running into a problem where the only constructors avaliable to me ask for a `refOrOutKeyword` `SyntaxToken`. Passing `null` is not allowed, moreover `Syntax.ParseToken("")` fails. `Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.RefKeyword)` and `Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.OutKeyword)` are both unsuitable, as they insert either `ref` or `out`:

```
var ctorArgs = Syntax.ArgumentList();
var ctor = enclosingType.Members
                        .OfType<ConstructorDeclarationSyntax>()
                        .OrderBy(cc => cc.ParameterList.Parameters.Count)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
if (ctor != null)
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a new ArgumentSyntax instance.
    // public static ArgumentSyntax Argument(
    //     NameColonSyntax nameColon,
    //     SyntaxToken refOrOutKeyword,
    // ExpressionSyntax expression);
    ctorArgs.AddArguments((
        from param in ctor.ParameterList.Parameters
        select Syntax.Argument(
                Syntax.NameColon(param.Identifier.ValueText),
                Syntax.ParseToken("") /* <- what to put here */, 
                Syntax.DefaultExpression(param.Type))
    ).ToArray());
}
```

I've not found any suitable documentation to elucidate how I can create named arguments either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, looking how is such code represented at runtime helps. If I parse code that uses named arguments and look at `RefOrOutKeyword.Kind` of the `ArgumentSyntax` in question, it's `None`. So, you need to do the same thing: create a `SyntaxToken` with `None` as its `Kind`:

```
Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.None)
```

Comment: I had Quoter working until I went to the latest CTP. I'd also foolishly overwritten the working executable. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the trouble! Quoter is now updated for the September CTP.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was right under my nose the whole time, if you'd like a "null" or empty `SyntaxToken`, use `default`:

```
Syntax.Argument(
    Syntax.NameColon(param.Identifier.ValueText),
    default(SyntaxToken),
    Syntax.DefaultExpression(param.Type))
// Produces output like:
//    baseUri: default(string)
```

Comment: This might be obvious, but using `null` is not possible here, because `SyntaxToken` is a `struct`. And writing `new SyntaxToken()` would work the same, but I guess that doesn't express the intent well.

Comment: @svick: I'd noted the struct restrictions indirectly in my question. I'm adding extensions to smooth over these rough edges in practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in two steps:

```
Syntax.Argument(Syntax.DefaultExpression(param.Type))
      .WithNameColon(Syntax.NameColor(param.Identifier.ValueText))
```